# Flagging/hiding posts twitter api 1.1 php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, twitter

I am calling a php file from an angular front end, and then showing a timeline of tweets.

The php file checks for tweets every ten minutes, and after this time updates a json file which is then called from angular. I want to create an admin ability to flag/hide posts from appearing in the timeline. Does anyone have any advice on how this should be done?

Should it be done by making a `POST` request from Angular to the php file to set a flag on a tweet? If so how would this be done?

My code looks like this.

**php**

```
<?php
require_once('twitter_proxy.php');
// Twitter OAuth Config options
$oauth_access_token = '*****';
$oauth_access_token_secret = '*****';
$consumer_key = '*****';
$consumer_secret = '*****';
$user_id = '*****';
$screen_name = 'StackOverflow';
$count = 5;
$twitter_url = 'statuses/user_timeline.json';
$twitter_url .= '?user_id=' . $user_id;
$twitter_url .= '&screen_name=' . $screen_name;
$twitter_url .= '&count=' . $count;
// Create a Twitter Proxy object from our twitter_proxy.php class
$twitter_proxy = new TwitterProxy(
    $oauth_access_token,            // 'Access token' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $oauth_access_token_secret,     // 'Access token secret' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $consumer_key,                  // 'API key' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $consumer_secret,               // 'API secret' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $user_id,                       // User id (http://gettwitterid.com/)
    $screen_name,                   // Twitter handle
    $count                          // The number of tweets to pull out
);

function checkForUpdates($twitter_proxy, $twitter_url) {
    $tweets = $twitter_proxy->get($twitter_url);
    $data = array ('twitter_result' => $tweets, 'timestamp' => time());
    file_put_contents('twitter_result.json', json_encode($data));
}

//check if the file exists
if(!file_exists('twitter_result.json')) {
    //Invoke the get method to retrieve results via a cURL request
    //and create a file with timestamp containing tweets
    checkForUpdates($twitter_proxy, $twitter_url);

}else {
    //if file exists check it has not been updated in 10 minutes
    //if not update the tweets and timestamp
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('twitter_result.json'));
    if ($data->{"timestamp"} > (time() - 10 * 60)) {
        checkForUpdates($twitter_proxy, $twitter_url);
    }
}
```

**factory.js**

```
app.factory('testMedia', ['$http', function($http){
    return {
        updateTwitter: function() {
            return $http({
                url: 'get_tweets.php',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        },
        fetchTwitter: function() {
            return $http({
                url: 'twitter_result.json',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

**twitterCtrl.js**

```
app.controller("twitterCtrl", ["$routeParams", "testMedia", function ($routeParams, socialMedia) {
    twitterCtrl = this;
    this.twitterPosts = [];   

    testMedia.updateTwitter()
    .then(function(){
        testMedia.fetchTwitter()
        .then(function(response){
            var result = JSON.parse(response.data.twitter_result);
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                result[i].created_at = new Date(result[i].created_at);
                twitterCtrl.twitterPosts.push(result[i]);
            }      
        })
    });
}]);
```